# Powershell not showing node text if node has attributes

Tags: xml, powershell, innertext

I try to process Peppol xml invoices. Sometimes the same node has attributes and sometimes does not. How can I get the text of a node regardless of it having attributes?

```
$xml=[xml]@"
<Invoice>
    <PaymentMeans>
        <PayeeFinancialAccount>
            <ID schemeID="IBAN">BE29 3100 0335</ID>
            <ID2>BE29 3100 0335</ID2>
        </PayeeFinancialAccount>
    </PaymentMeans>
</Invoice>
"@

$Invoice=$xml.Invoice
$BIC=$Invoice.PaymentMeans.PayeeFinancialAccount.ID.InnerText
$BIC2=$Invoice.PaymentMeans.PayeeFinancialAccount.ID2.InnerText
Write-Output "BIC                       : $BIC" 
Write-Output "BIC                       : $BIC2"
```

.InnerText, .InnerXml, .OuterXml and .'#text' are not the solutions.

A working solution is however the use of select-xml that uses Xpath.

```
$BIC3=(select-xml 'PaymentMeans/PayeeFinancialAccount/ID' $Invoice).node."#text"
$BIC4=(select-xml 'PaymentMeans/PayeeFinancialAccount/ID2' $Invoice).node."#text"
Write-Output $BIC3 
Write-Output $BIC4
```

It seems I have to rewrite the script but I hope there are other solutions as well.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide a sample xml with and without attributes and the exact expected output from that sample?

Comment: Hi Jack, the xml is already in the post. If you copy paste this into PS you will see that either one shows a result. I need thm both to show a result.

Comment: Powershell’s “xml type accelerator” is what lets you navigate xml nodes by name without using the .net DOM methods (e.g. ```$Invoice.PaymentMeans```). If an element contains only inner text, it gets added as a ```string``` property on its parent, otherwise it gets added as a ```System.Xml.XmlElement```. You could do something like ```if($Invoice…ID -is [string]) { # return ID } else { # return ID.InnerText }```

Comment: In your question you say you have the same node with and without the attribute, but your xml has two different named node, one with and one without an attribute.

Comment: Hi jack, you're right of course but that was for the sake of the example.

Comment: Thank you, mclayton,  that is really helpful. I found this link that I should study about both PS methods to access xmld data: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-data-basics-xml/#:~:text=most%20from%20XML.-,Accessing%20XML%20data%20in%20PowerShell,the%20object%20dot%2Dnotation%20approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mclayton,: Powershell’s “xml type accelerator” is what lets you navigate xml nodes by name without using the .net DOM methods (e.g. $Invoice.PaymentMeans). If an element contains only inner text, it gets added as a string property on its parent, otherwise it gets added as a System.Xml.XmlElement. You could do something like if($Invoice…ID -is [string]) { # return ID } else { # return ID.InnerText }

```
$xml=[xml]@"
<Invoice>
    <PaymentMeans>
        <PayeeFinancialAccount>
            <ID schemeID="IBAN">BE29 3100 0335 4064</ID>
            <ID2>BE29 3100 0335 4064</ID2>
        </PayeeFinancialAccount>
    </PaymentMeans>
</Invoice>
"@
$Invoice=$xml.Invoice
$BIC=$Invoice.PaymentMeans.PayeeFinancialAccount.ID
$BICID=if($BIC -is [string]) { $BIC } else { $BIC.InnerText } 
Write-Output "BIC: $BICID"
```

Comment: Hi, @Kees Netelvrees, thanks to share your solution with the community. Please, could you check you question as resolved? Congrats!